Why HTML Registration Form Data is not Received in django
I have below configurations of demo\urls.py, user\urls.py, views.py & HTML Form.
Still when I press the submit button of HTML Form it says File Not Found. Taking help from ChatGPT which provided two Solutions as mentioned in attached file, even then I am getting Error. What to do
demo\urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user', views.register),
]

user\urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register),
]

views.py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        created_at = request.POST.get("created_at")
        updated_at = request.POST.get("updated_at")

I have following code in HTML Form
 <form id="NewUser" method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
        
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
                
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
                
    <script>
   // Generate current datetime for Hidden fields
       var current_datetime = new Date().toISOString();
       document.getElementById('current_datetime').value = current_datetime;
    </script>

 <!-- Hidden fields for created_at and updated_at -->
 <input type="hidden" name="created_at" value="{{ current_datetime }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="updated_at" value="{{ current_datetime }}">

 <button type="submit">Register</button>
                
</form>
        
</body>
</html>

When I press the submit button of HTML Form it says File Not Found. What is the Error & how to fix it
I had used ChatGPT & his response as follow
The issue you’re encountering is likely due to the way you’ve configured your URL patterns in Django. Let’s go through the configuration and identify the problem:
URL Configuration:
You have two different URL configurations:
In demo/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user', views.register),
]

In user/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register),
]

The problem here is that the URL pattern in demo/urls.py for the register view is catching the URL /user, and there’s no pattern for the base URL (/). So when you submit the form, the action points to {% url 'register' %}, which resolves to /user, but the form is being submitted to /user/register.
Form Action:
In your HTML form, the action attribute is set to {% url 'register' %}, which will resolve to the URL /user because of the configuration in demo/urls.py. However, your actual URL pattern for the register view is /user/register, as defined in user/urls.py.
Solution:
You have a couple of options to resolve this issue:
Update your form action in the HTML template to point directly to /user/register:

Alternatively, you can modify your URL configurations to align with your application structure:
In demo/urls.py:
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include('user.urls')), # Include user URLs
]

In user/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register), # Add a trailing slash
]

With this setup, your form action in the HTML template can remain as {% url 'register' %}, and it will correctly resolve to /user/register.
Choose the approach that best fits your application structure and preferences. Either way, ensure that the form action matches the URL pattern where the register view is defined.
I have tried both suggestion, even then I am getting Error
Not Found: /
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:20] “GET / HTTP/1.1” 404 2162
Not Found: /cart.json
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:20] “GET /cart.json HTTP/1.1” 404 2207
Not Found: /
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:21] “GET / HTTP/1.1” 404 2162
Not Found: /cart.json
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:21] “GET /cart.json HTTP/1.1” 404 2207
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:25] “GET /admin/user/userprofile/ HTTP/1.1” 200 4977
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:25] “GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1” 200 3195
Not Found: /cart.json
[04/Apr/2024 00:42:26] “GET /cart.json HTTP/1.1” 404 2207

How to fix this so that Form Data should go to django
Thanks in Advance

use path('register/', views.register, name='register'),

That being said, where does the /cart.json originates from? There is no view for that at all..

In the log I also don't see a POST request to the register, in fact no POST request at all?

minus one for lack of responsiveness.

Hi @willeM_VanOnsem
I have tried as you have mentioned i.e. use path('register/', views.register, name='register'), still HTML Form do not send data to django
I have not added or used /cart.json. Don't know where it is coming from
POST is mentioned in method only

minus one for lack of responsiveness. –
willeM
I was checking your response in django to give you a proper feedback

But there is no POST request in the log, the Not Found is not that important. Is there anything in the developer console why it does not make a POST request?

Just use django official documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/   It's very easy to understand and follow through.  It's obvious, you urls are not matching in frist part. You need another url to process post request of the form.

Furthermore, what endpoint does generate the HTML form?

Chat GPT is good, but it will not be able to understand 100% what's on your mind /design. Obviously, {% url 'register' %} means path /register, so that's the path form is going get submit.

Thanks @willeM_VanOnsem * POST - Nothing on the Developer Console for POST. Where should I put this POST request * Django Docs - I will go through them - Thanks for that.

@Pycm: no, I suspect that the templated is not rendered at all, and therefore makes no request. {% url 'register' %} should error since there is no view with tath name=....

May be, then how he clicked the submit button? Did he just open the template on its own. Without through django server? I think, it's more easy to just configure urls correctly, than trying to find and solve specific problems.

@Pycm: likely by opening the template (well, template...) in the browser directly, so omitting the Django server process.

I think, it's more easy to just configure urls correctly, than trying to find and solve specific problems.   *Yes I am working on that - Thanks

Look @willeM_ Van Onsem's answer. View should always return something / html/url. Don't create views with same name.

I suspect that you don't render the template, and thus the {% url 'register' %} is not interpolated, but thus is the value for the action="…", and therefore does not send the data to the server.
You thus save the template in user/templates/user/register.html (with the first user the directory of the app). The template looks like:
<!-- user/templates/user/register.html -->
<html>
 <body>
 <form id="NewUser" method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
        
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
                
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>

 <button type="submit">Register</button>
                
</form>
</body>
</html>

Now we provide a name for the register, function, like:
# demo/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include('user.urls')),
]

# user/urls.py

from user.views import register

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
]
and in the view, we render:
# user/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
    return render(request, 'user/register.html')
In order to view the form, not only POST it, we visit localhost:8000/user/register (without the .html, and with 8000 as port).
This will interpolate the template, and thus replace {% url 'register' %} with /user/register/.

Taking help from ChatGPT which provided two Solutions as mentioned in attached file, even then I am getting Error.

Please don't use code you don't understand. That is true for codefragments you find online, but also for code fragments generated by ChatGPT. A paper named "How Secure is Code Generated by ChatGPT?" [arXiv] concluded that ChatGPT is aware of security vulnerabilities in the sense that if you ask about a vulnerability, it can explains the vulnerability, but does not take it into account when writing code. There are some small indications that chatbots like ChatGPT might provide a working example, but therefore that example is often not very good with respect to efficiency, security, architecture, etc.

Let me Check by making Recommended Changes & then Update you

Hello @willeM_ Van Onsem. Can I chat with you outside stackoverflow?

Thanks @willeM after making above changes, it shows html page with three fields i.e., Name, Email & Password. But when I entered data & press the Submit button nothing happens

@Shahzad: normally if you submit, it will make a POST request to the same view with the data, and then rerender the template again, so you probably should add a print(..) for  example in the if request.method == 'POST' to see if it triggers the view with the data.

Thanks @willeM_VanOnsem I have Added Print to check Result. Now it is Showing Data in Console. Now Data has reached to Django. Next Step is to Save it in  Sqlite using following  up = UserProfile.objects.create(name=name, email=email, password=password, created_at=created_at, updated_at=updated_at)
up.save()

@Shahzad: please don't save raw passwords: hash the passwrods, also don't manually specify created_at, or updated_at. Why not use Django's user model, or subclass from that?
